# How to display Custom Error in Frontend or custom tests?

Tags: solidity, custom-errors

I am using custom error like these:

```
error BadIndexError();

revert BadIndexError();
```

Now, if I want to retrieve these errors how would I retrieve it in frontend?

Plus, I am using custom framework for tests for my company. How would I retrieve such errors in my tests as well? Right now I just get revert and no error message.

Any simple way? Does ethersjs support it?

Answer (score 0):

I have some posts about custom errors in my blog.

for Ethers.js:
https://blog.emn178.cc/en/post/ethers-js-parse-custom-error/

for Web3.js:
https://blog.emn178.cc/en/post/using-web3-js-to-parse-custom-error/

If you use hardhat for testing, you can check [document](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/reference#.revertedwithcustomerror), usage will looks like

```
await expect(
 contract.someMethod()
).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(contract, 'BadIndexError');
```

If you use custom framework for tests, you may use parseCustomError function mentioned in my blog and check its name and args.